# How to get a list of selected rows in Syncfusion.WPF.DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, syncfusion

I use Syncfusion in my **WPF** project. The following is a **DataGrid** with multiple selection modes:

```
<grid:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                 SelectionMode="Multiple"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedRows}"
                 BorderThickness="1"
                 NavigationMode="Row"
                 BorderBrush="Black"
                 CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=cellStyle}"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=headerStyle}"
                 ColumnSizer="AutoLastColumnFill"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=dataPager}">
                        <grid:SfDataGrid.Columns>

                            <grid:GridCheckBoxSelectorColumn MappingName="SelectorColumn"
                                                             Width="30" />

                            <grid:GridTextColumn  AllowDragging="False"
                                                  HeaderText="Id"
                                                  MappingName="EquipmentId"
                                                  IsHidden="True" />
                            <grid:GridTextColumn  AllowDragging="False"
                                                  HeaderText="Code"
                                                  MappingName="EquipmentCode" />
                            <grid:GridTextColumn  AllowDragging="False"
                                                  HeaderText="Title"
                                                  MappingName="EquipmentTitle" />
                        </grid:SfDataGrid.Columns>

                    </grid:SfDataGrid>
```

I want to get a list of selected rows (their Ids that exist in the first hidden column) in the ViewModel. How can I achieve this?

**Note:** I use Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` in the XAML code and then, I used the following property in the ViewModel:

```
  public class EquipmentIdentitySettingViewModel: ObservableObject {
  //...Some codes here
  private ObservableCollection < object > _selectedItems;

  public ObservableCollection < object > SelectedItems {
    get {
      return _selectedItems;
    }
    set {
      SetProperty(ref _selectedItems, value);
    }
  }
  public ICommand ApplyCommand {
    get;
  }
  public EquipmentIdentitySettingViewModel() {
    ApplyCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ApplyChanges());
  }
  private void ApplyChanges() {
    if (SelectedItems != null) {
      foreach(Equipment item in SelectedItems) {
        MessageBox.Show(item.EquipmentCode.ToString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem solved.

Comment: This solves the issue, but consider the following: View models should implement from `INotifyPropertyChanged` instead of inheriting `ObservableObject` and strong types should be used when possible.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if it helps but i know how to only get the selected item by using
this in xaml side

```
<grid:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" SelectionChanged="GetSelected">
```

this is in c# side

```
private void GetSelected(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
Object selectedItem = dataGrid.SelectedItem as Object;

        }
```